# log line number in vim whenever a line is deleted

Tags: vim, editor

I have an application that generates a txt file with thousands of lines. I have to delete some lines manually by going through the file (using vim). However, I might need to generate the same file again if a change in format is required. That will make me go through the file again to delete the same lines.

The solution to avoid deleting manually repeatedly is that vim somehow logs the line number when I delete a line. I can then use some script to remove those lines. Is it possible to get this behavior in vim?

Otherwise, is there any other editor to get this behavior? There are many lines I have to delete and it's not feasible for me to log each line number manually.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a work a human should do.

Comment: @romainl Yeah that's what I want. To log line numbers automatically.

Comment: Can you not use a regex to match the lines you want to remove? e.g. `:s/^startswith.*endswith$//` (you can tailor it to your needs)

Comment: Use [`diff`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) + [`patch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/patch). Or a version control like `git`.

Comment: `diff`/`patch` are like recipes for how to convert one file into another. Your problem may still require an extra step since you want the formatting to be different the next time you do this. But at least those tools will show you the exact line numbers you deleted, even if you can't apply the patch directly.

Comment: @wxz Yeah, I think I can extract line numbers from diff. I'll try it and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) and [wxz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13020139/wxz), I was able to use `git-diff` of the file to extract the deleted lines by using node package [gitdiff-parser](https://github.com/ecomfe/gitdiff-parser) for parsing the diff.

```
const gitDiffParser = require('gitdiff-parser')
const { exec } = require("child_process");

let p = new Promise( (res,rej) => {
    exec("git diff -U0 file.txt", (error, stdout) => {
        res(stdout)
    });
});
p.then(s=>{
    diff = gitDiffParser.parse(s);
    diff[0].hunks.forEach(element => {
        console.log(`start: ${element.oldStart}, end: ${element.oldStart + element.oldLines - 1}`)
    });
})
```

Another solution or say hack was to append line number in each line of the file and extract the undeleted line numbers after removing the required lines.